# inserción de ID desigual

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Estoy trabajando con inserciones desde un proyecto que estoy realizando en C# (ASP.NET) y todo iba bien hasta que en el ID de mi tabla comenzó a ser desigual, alguien podría explicar por que del 41 se paso al 1007, dejo de ejemplo mi código y mi resultado final en SQL Server.

```
public partial class App_Contador : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("server=SISTEMAS ; database=clientes ; integrated security = true");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void aumentoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int count = int.Parse(folioTextBox.Text);
        count++;
        folioTextBox.Text = count.ToString();
        fechaTextBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");

        conexion.Open();
        string fol = folioTextBox.Text;
        string fecha = fechaTextBox.Text;
        string cadena = "insert into Folios(Folio, Mes) values ('" + fol + "','" + fecha + "')";
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(cadena, conexion);
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        respuestaLabel.Text = ("Los datos se guardaron correctamente");

        conexion.Close();

    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el ID por lo regualar el autoincrementable y si realizaste muchas pruebas posiblemente lo que necesitas en hacer Truncate table nametable para que tu ID se reinicie a 0

Comment: Hola! Podrías por favor, incluir en tu pregunta (editándola) la definición de la tabla? En lo posible, como texto y no como imagen.

Comment: Si el que el id de registro no coincida con el "orden" de los registros influye en tu aplicación, tal vez deberías revisar la lógica de la aplicación.